# Functional differential equations

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can somebody help guide books about Functional differential equation with a lot of exercises?

Thanks for recommending.

Comment: For the beginning.

Comment: Are you asking if there are books about Functional Equations? Or Differential Equations? I would think the intersection of the two would still reside within simply Differential Equations.

Comment: @gdepaul The OP's question is completely clear: books on [functional differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation).

Comment: @kimwenasa If you are looking for exercises, I would try Hal L. Smith's [An Introduction to Delay Differential Equations with Applications to the Life Sciences](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-7646-8).